# Showing Image on Index.cshtml page with Entityframework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, razorengine

I have this:

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(UserProfile userprofile, HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {

            if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
            {


                // extract only the fielname
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                // store the file inside ~/App_Data/uploads folder
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), fileName);
                path = Url.Content(Path.Combine("~/~/App_Data/uploads", fileName));
                file.SaveAs(path);
            }



            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                string username = User.Identity.Name;
                // Get the userprofile
                UserProfile user = db.userProfiles.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName.Equals(username));

                // Update fields
                user.Image = new byte[file.ContentLength];
                file.InputStream.Read(user.Image, 0, file.ContentLength);


                user.FirstName = userprofile.FirstName;
                user.LastName = userprofile.LastName;
                user.Email = userprofile.Email;
                user.Motto = userprofile.Motto;

                user.PlaceOfBirth = userprofile.PlaceOfBirth;
                user.HowManyBikes = userprofile.HowManyBikes;
                user.BesideYourBeth = userprofile.BesideYourBeth;
                user.NicestRide = userprofile.NicestRide;
                user.WorstRide = userprofile.WorstRide;
                user.AmountKmPerYear = userprofile.AmountKmPerYear;
                user.AverageSpeed = userprofile.AverageSpeed;
                user.AbleToChatWhileRiding = userprofile.AbleToChatWhileRiding;
                user.PhoneNumber = userprofile.PhoneNumber;

                db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;

                db.SaveChanges();

                return RedirectToAction("Edit", "Account");
            }

            return View(userprofile);
        }
```

And View:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Motto)
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PlaceOfBirth)
                                    </td>

                                    <td><img width="200px" height="150px" src="@Url.Content(item.Image)" /></td>



                                    <td>

                                        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id })

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
            }

                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br />
                Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount

                @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index",
    new { page, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter }))
```

So I want to show the image in de index file, as thumbnail. The image is already saved in the database, and I try to show the image like this:
 `<td><img width="200px" height="150px" src="@Url.Content(item.Image)" /></td>` but that doesnt work.

Thank you for your help

and I have the Index, like this:

```
 @foreach (var item in Model)
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Motto)
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PlaceOfBirth)
                                    </td>

                                    <td>
                                        <img width="200" height="150" src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "Account", new { item.Id })">
                                    </td>



                                    <td>

                                        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id })

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
            }
```

but I look in chrome and I see the dimensions of: img 74x22 and also strange because the image is comming from:

```
img {
background-image: url('../Images/Large.JPG');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: top;
background-size: cover;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
```

so for every profile the images are the same, but the images are stored in: ~/App_Data/uploads.

oke, I uncomment the img{} in site.css and now I see the right dimensions, but the images are broken

```
GET http://localhost:41787/Account/GetImage/34 500 (Internal Server Error) Account:179
event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.
```

The accountController looks now this:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(UserProfile userprofile, HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {

            if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
            {


                // extract only the fielname
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                // store the file inside ~/App_Data/uploads folder
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), fileName);
               // path = Url.Content(Path.Combine("~/~/App_Data/uploads", fileName));
                file.SaveAs(path);
            }



            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                string username = User.Identity.Name;
                // Get the userprofile
                UserProfile user = db.userProfiles.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName.Equals(username));

                // Update fields
                user.Image = new byte[file.ContentLength];
                file.InputStream.Read(user.Image, 0, file.ContentLength);
                user.ImageMimeType = file.ContentType;


                user.FirstName = userprofile.FirstName;
                user.LastName = userprofile.LastName;
                user.Email = userprofile.Email;
                user.Motto = userprofile.Motto;

                user.PlaceOfBirth = userprofile.PlaceOfBirth;
                user.HowManyBikes = userprofile.HowManyBikes;
                user.BesideYourBeth = userprofile.BesideYourBeth;
                user.NicestRide = userprofile.NicestRide;
                user.WorstRide = userprofile.WorstRide;
                user.AmountKmPerYear = userprofile.AmountKmPerYear;
                user.AverageSpeed = userprofile.AverageSpeed;
                user.AbleToChatWhileRiding = userprofile.AbleToChatWhileRiding;
                user.PhoneNumber = userprofile.PhoneNumber;

                db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;

                db.SaveChanges();

                return RedirectToAction("Edit", "Account");
            }

            return View(userprofile);
        }

        public FileContentResult GetImage(int itemId)
        {
            UserProfile user = db.userProfiles.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id.Equals(itemId));
            if (user != null)
                return File(user.Image, user.ImageMimeType);
            else return null;
        }
```

and the view(Index.cshtml):

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Motto)
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PlaceOfBirth)
                                </td>

                                <td>
                                    <img width="200" height="150" src='@Url.Action("GetImage", "Account", new { item.Id  }, Request.Url.Scheme)'>
                                </td>



                                <td>

                                    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id })

                                </td>
                            </tr>
        }
```

But is this correct??

```
<td>
                                        <img alt="" src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "Account", new {item.Id })" width="200" height="150"  class="Image" />
                                    </td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of

```
<img width="200px" height="150px" src="@Url.Content(item.Image)" />
```

put

```
<img width="200px" height="150px" src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "Account", new { item.Id })
```

Add in your account controller this method :

```
public FileContentResult GetImage(int itemId)
{
UserProfile user = db.userProfiles.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id.Equals(itemId));
if(user != null)
return File(user.Image, user.ImageMimeType);
else return null;
}
```

You must add a new field to the user table , ImageMimeType.

In this section

```
// Update fields
user.Image = new byte[file.ContentLength];
file.InputStream.Read(user.Image, 0, file.ContentLength);
```

add

```
user.ImageMimeType = file.ContentType;
```

And that's it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply Marius, but what is the type of ImageMimeType? I have it like this in Model(UserProfile)  public string ImageMimeType { get; set; }

Comment: But the images are broken, not visible

Comment: Check my answer, you must add this line of code user.ImageMimeType = file.ContentType in the Edit action; existing registrations will not work, but if you add the line of code the new ones should.

Comment: I improved something: <td>
                                        <img width="200" height="150" src='@Url.Action("GetImage", "Account", new { item.Id  }, Request.Url.Scheme)'>
                                    </td> but still dont see the image: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) why it cant find the images?

Comment: Check GetImage with debug and see if it returns what it should.

Comment: But it doesnt hit the  public FileContentResult GetImage(int itemId) in the accountController

Comment: I debug the view(Index) but it doesnt hit:  <td>
                                        <img width="200" height="150" src='@Url.Action("GetImage", "Account", new { item.Id  }, Request.Url.Scheme)'>
                                    </td>

Comment: If I look ate:  @foreach (var item in Model) I see by item: Image = {byte[1466972]}, but by: ImageMimeType = null

Comment: You must check the ImageMimeType is saved in the database; also, ImageMimeType won't be populated for old registrations, only new ones.

Comment: ok, I made new, and now I see this by var Item in Model: ImageMimeType = "image/png" but if I debug in index.cshtml it still doestn hit: <td>
                                        <img width="200" height="150" src='@Url.Action("GetImage", "Account", new { item.Id  })'>
                                    </td> and the picture is still not shown, it is broken

Comment: But how can it that the image is still broken, but I see in the db: image/png

Comment: Hi Marius, but why I cant see the photo?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out, try the url link like this src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "Account", new { id = item.Id })" .

Comment: If I do that , then I will see this:   src="/Account/GetImage/42"

Comment: To my knowledge, it should be working,  I have no other ideas at this point, sorry .

Comment: oh my god!!!!!!!!!!!! I just changed this:  public ActionResult GetImage(int id), itemId  to id and now it works!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: But I want to have to image also on the detail page, but then: <img width="200" height="150" src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "Account", new { id = item.Id })">*@ doesnt work because I dont have an Item